# rich text not formatted on vf pdf properly

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, visualforce-template, dynamic-vf-component, vf-email-template

I have created a vf page pdf and use a custom RTF field but on PDF it is not rendering properly
i tried outputText and OutputField tag but not able to fix the issue.

on **Detail page Image is below**

[image]

On **PDF PAGE Image is below**

[image]

**Code is below**

```
<td><apex:outputField value="{!ord.Shipment_Details__c}"  /></td>
```

Comment: Please add minimal required code.

Comment: There is an Idea out there thats askin for this feature, so it will most likely not be possible in a easy / safe way.
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bab5AAA

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for space between sentences

`<apex:outputText escape="false"  value="{!SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(item.Product_Desc__c, '<p>', ''), '</p>', '<br/>')}"></apex:outputText>`